OnPress function not working as expected when changing the height attribute on neighbouring view in React Native Screen
I have a sidebar view which has a button which when pressed should navigate to another page in my app. However if I remove the height attribute from a neighbouring view the button is not pressable. If I add a height attribute to my wikiView styles the button then works. I am beside myself on how changing a neighbouring view's height attribute can make an another views pressable button work/not work.
MainSideBarWeb.js
import React, { useState, Component, useEffect } from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  ScrollView,
  Image,
  TextInput,
  Button,
  Alert,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Modal,
  Pressable,
  StatusBar
} from "react-native";
import {SafeAreaView, SafeAreaProvider} from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
import { useIsFocused } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { registerRootComponent } from 'expo';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createNativeStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import constants from './Constants.js';
import { styles } from './CommonStylesWeb.js';
import RNPickerSelect from 'react-native-picker-select';

const STYLES = ['default', 'dark-content', 'light-content'];
const TRANSITIONS = ['fade', 'slide', 'none'];

const MainSideBarWeb = () => {
  const [hidden, setHidden] = useState(false);
  const [sideBarContent, setSideBarContent] = useState('');
  const [statusBarStyle, setStatusBarStyle] = useState(STYLES[0]);
  const [statusBarTransition, setStatusBarTransition] = useState(
    TRANSITIONS[0],
  );
  const changeStatusBarVisibility = () => {
    setHidden(!hidden);
    if(hidden) {
        setSideBarContent('')
    }
    else {
        setSideBarContent("Cancer Types \n Cancer Drugs \n Cancer Genes")
    }
  };

    const changeStatusBarStyle = () => {
      const styleId = STYLES.indexOf(statusBarStyle) + 1;
      if (styleId === STYLES.length) {
        setStatusBarStyle(STYLES[0]);
      } else {
        setStatusBarStyle(STYLES[styleId]);
      }
    };

    const changeStatusBarTransition = () => {
      const transition = TRANSITIONS.indexOf(statusBarTransition) + 1;
      if (transition === TRANSITIONS.length) {
        setStatusBarTransition(TRANSITIONS[0]);
      } else {
        setStatusBarTransition(TRANSITIONS[transition]);
      }
    };

    return (
        <SafeAreaProvider>
          <SafeAreaView style={styles.sideBar}>
            <StatusBar
              animated={true}
              backgroundColor="#61dafb"
              barStyle={statusBarStyle}
              showHideTransition={statusBarTransition}
              hidden={hidden}
            />
            <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
              <Button style={styles.buttonContainer}
                title="Toggle StatusBar"
                onPress={changeStatusBarVisibility}
              />
            </View>
            {hidden &&
            <View style={[
              styles.sideBar,
              {
                // Try setting `flexDirection` to `"row"`.
                flexDirection: 'column',
              },
            ]}>
               <TouchableOpacity style={{backgroundColor: "red", padding: 20}} onPress={()=> {
                   console.log('does not work');
                   }
                 }>
                 <Text>Press Me</Text>
               </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
            }

          </SafeAreaView>
        </SafeAreaProvider>
   );
};

export { MainSideBarWeb };


CancerHomepageWeb.js
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import React, { useState, Component, useEffect } from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  ScrollView,
  Image,
  TextInput,
  Button,
  Alert,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Modal,
  Pressable
} from "react-native";
import { useIsFocused } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { registerRootComponent } from 'expo';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createNativeStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import constants from './Constants.js';
import { styles } from './CommonStylesWeb.js';
import RNPickerSelect from 'react-native-picker-select';
import { MainSideBarWeb } from './MainSideBarWeb'

const CancerHomepageWeb = ({navigation}) => {
    const [cancerWiki, setCancerWiki] = useState("");
    const [cancerType, setCancerType] = useState("");
    const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState(null);
    const [selectedLabel, setSelectedLabel] = useState(null);
    const [options, setOptions] = useState([]);
    const [cancerWikiContent, setCancerWikiContent] = useState("");
    //const navigation = useNavigation();
    console.log("navigation ", navigation);
    useEffect(() => {
        const getData = async () => {

            var urlCancerWiki = await constants.getServerURL() + 'cancers_wiki';
            console.warn(urlCancerWiki);
            let resultCancerWiki = await fetch(urlCancerWiki, {
                method: "GET", mode: 'cors'
                }).then(response => response.json())
                    .then(response => {
                        if (response) {
                            console.warn(response)
                            setCancerWiki(response)
                        }
                });
        };
        getData();
    }, []);
    async function handleChangeCancer(value, index) {
      console.warn("CANCER HAS CHANGED");
      setSelectedValue(value);
      console.warn(value)
      if(index > 0) {
          indexOffset = index - 1;
          console.warn(options[indexOffset].label);
          setSelectedLabel(options[indexOffset].label);

          const url = await constants.getServerURL() + 'cancer_wiki';
          console.warn(url);
          let result = fetch(url, {
             method: 'POST',
             headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
             body: JSON.stringify({ id: value}),
             mode: 'cors'
           }).then(response => response.json())
             .then(response => {
                if (response) {
                    setCancerWikiContent(response)
                    setCancerWiki("")
                }
           });

      }
    };
    const searchCancers = async() => {
        const url = await constants.getServerURL() + 'cancer_name';
        console.warn(url);
        console.warn(cancerType);
        if (cancerType.length >= 3) {
            let result = fetch(url, {
               method: 'POST',
               headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
               body: JSON.stringify({ cancer_type: cancerType}),
               mode: 'cors'
             }).then(response => response.json())
               .then(response => {
               setOptions([]);
               optionsTemp = [];
               console.warn("GETTING CANCER RESPONSE")
               console.warn(response)
               if (response) {
                    //setCancer = response.cancers
                    console.warn("VALID CANCER RESPONSE")
                    response.map( (cancer) => {
                        optionsTemp.push(new Object({label:cancer.name , value: cancer.id}));
                    });
                    console.warn(optionsTemp)
                    setOptions(optionsTemp);
               } else {
                   console.warn("Error retrieving Cancer");
                   //setErrorMessage("Error Getting Cancers!");
                   //setErrorVisible(true);
               }
              });
        }
    }
    return (

    <View style={styles.sideBar}>
        <MainSideBarWeb />
        <StatusBar style="auto" />
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <TextInput
              style={styles.TextInput}
              placeholder="Cancers"
              placeholderTextColor="#003f5c"
              onChangeText={(cancerType) => setCancerType(cancerType)}
              onKeyPress={searchCancers}
            />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.selectBox}>
            <Text>Select Cancer</Text>
            <RNPickerSelect
              style={styles.container}
              items={options}
              onValueChange={(value, index)  =>
                handleChangeCancer(value,index)}
              value={selectedValue}
            />
            {selectedValue && <Text>Selected: {selectedLabel}</Text>}
        </View>
        <ScrollView>
             <View style={styles.wikiView}>
                 <Text>{cancerWikiContent}</Text>
                 <Text>{cancerWiki}</Text>
             </View>
        </ScrollView>
    </View>
);
}



export { CancerHomepageWeb };

CommonStylesWeb.js (where if wikiView's height is set MainSideBarWeb's button works, if it is not, button does not work.
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Image,
  TextInput,
  Button,
  Alert,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from "react-native";

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection:'column',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  container1: {
      flex: 1,
      flexDirection:'column',
      backgroundColor: 'white',
      alignItems: "left",
      justifyContent: "left",
  },
  container2: {
      flex: 2,
      flexDirection:'column',
      backgroundColor: 'white',
      alignItems: "left",
      justifyContent: "left",
    },
    container3: {
        flex: 3,
        flexDirection:'column',
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        alignItems: "left",
        justifyContent: "left",
      },
  selectBox: {
      backgroundColor: 'white',
      alignItems: "center",
      justifyContent: "center",
      marginLeft: 400,
      marginRight: 400,

  },
  wikiView: {
    backgroundColor: "#94C93D",
    borderRadius: 30,
    width: 1000,
    height: 300,
    marginBottom: 20,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    marginLeft: 300,
    marginRight: 250,
  },
  TextInput: {
    backgroundColor: "#94C93D",
    width: 1000,
    flex: 1,
    padding: 10,
    marginLeft: 20,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
    backButton: {
        alignItems: 'left',
        justifyContent: 'left',
        paddingVertical: 12,
        paddingHorizontal: 32,
        borderRadius: 4,
        elevation: 3,
        backgroundColor: '#2196F3',
    },

    scrollView: {
        marginHorizontal: 20,
        height: 500,
    },
    sideBar: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection:'column',
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        alignItems: "left",
        justifyContent: "left",
        backgroundColor: '#ECF0F1',
    },
    buttonOpen: {
      backgroundColor: '#F194FF',
    },
    buttonClose: {
      backgroundColor: '#2196F3',
    },
    buttonContainer: {
      backgroundColor: 'white',
      width: 100
    }
});

export { styles };


I ended up giving up on trying to create a sidebar menu using React Native Stylings. Instead I used the react native navigation drawer library to create a sidebar menu.
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-based-navigation/
Here is my code now - index.js
import React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';

import CancerHomepageWebWrapper from './CancerHomepageWebWrapper';
import ChemoHomepageWebWrapper from './ChemoHomepageWebWrapper';
import GeneHomepageWebWrapper from './ChemoHomepageWebWrapper';

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Cancer">
        <Drawer.Screen name="Cancer" component={CancerHomepageWebWrapper} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Chemo" component={ChemoHomepageWebWrapper} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Gene" component={GeneHomepageWebWrapper} />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

Here are my three sidebar containers:
CancerHomePageWebWrapper.js
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';
import { CancerHomepageWeb } from './CancerHomepageWeb.js';
import { ChemoHomepageWeb } from './ChemoHomepageWeb.js';

const CancerHomepageWebWrapper = ({ navigation }) => {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Cancers</Text>
      <CancerHomepageWeb/>
    </View>
  );
};

export default CancerHomepageWebWrapper;

ChemoHomepageWebWrapper.js
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { CancerHomepageWeb } from './CancerHomepageWeb.js';
import { ChemoHomepageWeb } from './ChemoHomepageWeb.js';

const ChemoHomepageWebWrapper = () => {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Chemo</Text>
      <ChemoHomepageWeb/>
    </View>
  );
};

export default ChemoHomepageWebWrapper;

GeneHomepageWebWrapper.js
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';
import { CancerHomepageWeb } from './CancerHomepageWeb.js';
import { ChemoHomepageWeb } from './ChemoHomepageWeb.js';

const GeneHomepageWebWrapper = ({ navigation }) => {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Cancer Genes</Text>
      <CancerHomepageWeb/>
    </View>
  );
};

export default GeneHomepageWebWrapper;

